# Side-loaded Windows 8.1 application generates an exception when calling methods of an RESTful Web API

Tags: rest, windows-8.1, dotnet-httpclient

I have developed a Line-of-Business (LOB) Windows 8.1 application for one of our clients. The app was developed in Visual Studio 2015, on my 64-bit Windows 8.1 Enterprise laptop. The application makes use of a RESTful Web API that is running under IIS Express on the same laptop. The IIS Express has been configured to expose the RESTful Web API to the outside world, such that I can make Web API calls with Fiddler from a different machine. My app works just fine when I test it with the VS2015 Simulator, even when I configure it to use the correct IP address of the Web API (not the localhost).

The client wants to deploy this app in production on some DELL tablets that will run Windows 10. I have one of these tablets and it has 64-bit Windows 10 Enterprise on it. When I side-load my app on the tablet, I launch it and I save in its settings the URL for the Web API service. I relaunch the app, but the first call into the Web API fails to complete. I log an exception informing me that "An error occurred while sending the request". The inner exception message is "Unable to connect to the remote server". The line of code that triggers this exception is this one:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await WebApiHttpClient.GetAsync("api/user", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

where the WebApiHttpClient object is a class static member constructed like this:

```
if (WebApiHttpClient == null)
{
   WebApiHttpClient = new HttpClient(WebApiAuthClientHandler)
   {
      BaseAddress = new Uri(_serviceUri),  // _serviceUri is a string that looks like this "http://10.120.5.201:53045"
      Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 150)
   };

   WebApiHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

The WebApiAuthClientHandler is also a class static member that is instantiated like this:

```
if (WebApiAuthClientHandler == null)
{
    WebApiAuthClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials,
        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic
    };
}
```

The exception is triggered about 21 seconds after my call so it can't be a timeout since the timeout is set to 150 seconds.

The Web API is running on my laptop, as I mentioned before and using the node.js iisexpress-proxy tool I managed to expose the local URL to the outside world so that I can make Web API calls using Fiddler running on the tablet.

Also, in my app's Package.appxmanifest/Capabilities I have checked the "Private Networks (Client & Server)".

The Event Viewer does not log any additional information.

Can anyone make a suggestion on why the error is triggered?
TIA,
Eddie

Comment: Forgot to mention that the app will have to use Windows Authentication, hence the particular way in which the HttpClientHandler is constructed.

Comment: The other thing worth mentioning is that Fiddler does not record any attempt for the Web API call even though it is running a filter for the Web API's URL and should be able to capture any attempt of a traffic heading to the specified IP address and port. That means that the "GetAsync" call is not even leaving the tablet, so to speak.

Comment: To add further context to this question, the nested message in the exception says: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 127.0.0.1:8888"

Answer (score 0):

The error message I have in my 3rd comment was caused by the fact that I had Fiddler running at the same time. When running without Fiddler, the application receives a different error, but that will be the subject of a different question here, on StackOverflow.